# How to return appended field when want to select specific column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I added a `full_name` field to `User` model like this:

```
protected $appends = ['full_name'];

public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->name . ' ' . $this->family;
}
```

On the other hand I want to select and return specific columns along with full_name field like this:

```
return  User::all('user_id', 'username', 'full_name')
```

But laravel gets this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `user_id`, `username`, `name`, `family`, `full_name` from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null)

How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to specify that in your select column.. it's already attached with your result set.

If you want specific columns, than you need to probably user $hidden attributes and make them visible whenever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use append attribute in query.

the `full_name` only can be access after query.. bcoz full_name is not attach with the result

```
$users = User::all();
return $users[0]->full_name; //this requred getFullNameAttribute like above
```

If you still want to do with query. Do in DB query instead.. this no need to $append attribute. full_name already attach with the result

```
return User::select('user_id', 'username' , DB::raw('CONCAT(name, " ", family) AS full_name'))->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can get two or more column value concated using query like this,

```
 return  $user = User::select('user_id', 'username',DB::raw("CONCAT('first_name', " ",'last_name') AS full_name" 'full_name');
```

Or if you want to concat column from retrieved array you can do like this,

```
$user = User::all();
foreach($user as $single){
   $user->full_name = $single->first_name ." ".$single->last_name
}
print_r($user);
```

happy coding.